# Constraint on constant in differential equation $ \frac{f'''}{f'}-\frac{3}{2}(\frac{f''}{f'})^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using the substitution
$$u=\frac{f''}{f'}$$
the differential equation
$$
\frac{f'''}{f'}-\frac{3}{2}\Bigl(\frac{f''}{f'}\Bigr)^2=0
$$
can be transformed to
$$u'-\frac{1}{2}u^2=0.$$
The solutions are then, fairly easily, calculated as
$$f(x)=A_1x+B_1,\qquad A_1\neq0,$$
and
$$f(x)=\frac{A_2}{x+C}+B_2,\qquad A_2\neq0.$$
But, the text book also suggests that $C\neq0$, something I don't understand.

Comment: If you have initial conditions at $x=0$, your solution can not be singular there.

Comment: You may want to read [Schwarzian derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative).